# Change default route after user is logged in MVC Framework

Tags: php

Using the MVC Framework style, the following router loads controllers once the keyword from "GET" url variable is found in the controllers folder and load its view(html) from the views folder.

I have `"login.php"`,`"signup.php"`,`"index.php"`,`"logout.php"`,`"ajax.php"`,`"get_started.php"` files in the controllers folder.

I have the following in the main directory:
`"index.php"(file)`,`".htaccess"(file)`,`"init.php"(file)`,`"app"(folder)`,`"assets"(folder)`

How do I make an example: `"home.php"` in the controllers folder the default page such that if there is no keyword "home" as url variable it will still work.

By doing this, the url address should then look like:`http://localhost/joacmedia/` and not `http://localhost/joacmedia/home` after the user is logged in.

How possible can I achieve this with .htaccess or app router?

**MY APP ROUTER:**

```
<?php

//DEFINE A CLASS OF APP
//CREATING THE ROUTER...
//LOAD A PAGE OR CONTROLLER ONCE THE "URL" GET VARIABLE IS FOUND AS CONTROLLER

class App
{

//DEFINE DEFAULT PROPERTIES FOR CONTROLLER AND METHOD
public $controller  = "login", $method = "index", $params = [];


public function __construct()
{

    $url = $this->splitUrl();
    
    //CHECK IF A CONTROLLER EXISTS
    if (file_exists("app/controllers/". strtolower($url[0])  .".php")) 
    {
        $this->controller = strtolower($url[0]);
        unset($url[0]);

    }
    else
    {

        //NO CONTROLLER FOUND
        //SHOW 404 PAGE
        include "app/views/404.php"; 
        //STOP THE SCRIPT IF A CONTROLLER IS NOT FOUND
        exit;
    }
    //LOAD CONTROLLER AND METHOD
    require ("app/controllers/". $this->controller .".php");

    //CHECK IF A CLASS EXISTS
    /*FOR DEBUG PURPOSES*/

    if (class_exists($this->controller)) 
    {
        
    //INSTANTIATE THIS CLASS
    $this->controller = new $this->controller;
    //LOOK FOR THE METHOD OF THIS CLASS INSTANTIATED ABOVE
    if (isset($url[1])) 
    {
        if (method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])) 
        {
            //OVERWITE DEFAULT METHOD
            $this->method = $url[1];
            unset($url[1]);
        }
    }

    //RUN THE CLASS AND METHOD
    $url = $this->params =  array_values($url);
    call_user_func_array([$this->controller,$this->method], $this->params);
    
    }
    else
    {
        //INSTANTIATE DEBUGER
        $DEBUG = new DEBUGER();
        $DEBUG->Logger($this->controller." : CLASS could not be found.");
    }
}


//THIS METHOD SPLIT URL RETURNING THE CONTROLLER CLASS AND METHOD
private function splitUrl()
{
    $url = isset($_GET["url"]) ? strtolower($_GET["url"]) : 'login';
    return explode("/", filter_var(trim($url,"/"), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL ));
} 
}
```

**HTACCESS FILE sitting in the main directory:**

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we're loading controllers based on the keyword(representing a class name) from the **$_GET['url']**

I was able to solve it by checking if user is logged in , if they are logged in and url is not set (that means if there is no keyword from url) , then we set default keyword('home') to load controller and if they are not logged in the default keyword to load controller is "login"

This way, if user is logged in and no keywrod is passed from url variable we will get our address as: `http://localhost/joacmedia/` and still get our page which will be used as home or dashboard.

```
//THIS METHOD SPLIT URL RETURNING THE CONTROLLER CLASS AND METHOD
private function splitUrl()
{
    $url = isset($_GET["url"]) ? strtolower($_GET["url"]) : ($this->isLoggedIn() ? 'home': "login");
    return explode("/", filter_var(trim($url,"/"), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL ));
}




public function isLoggedIn()
{
    //INSTANTIATE THE DATABASE CLASS
    $DB = new Database();

    if (
        isset($_SESSION['USER_SESSION_DATA']->url_address,
        $_SESSION['USER_SESSION_DATA']->id
        ) && 
        !empty($_SESSION['USER_SESSION_DATA'])
        ) 
    {
        
        return TRUE;

    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }


}
```